# Aligning TextViews and EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am attempting to align a couple `TextView`s on either side of an `EditText` on a single line. Some caveats to this:

1. I want them to pull tightly to each other, so for the `TextView` to the right of the `EditText` I want to make sure there is not a ton of space
2. Both `TextViews` may or not be there, depending on the customer setup, but it needs to be determined at runtime. So the fields need to shift if I set the visibility to NONE for either or both of the `TextViews`.
3. All 3 fields need to pull right on the screen.
4. The "suffix" (`TextView` to the right) will vary in size up to 10 characters, but I would like it to autofill the space needed.

This is what I would like to see:

[image]

But this is what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see the prefix and suffix ($ and US) are merging together, rather than splitting on each side of the `EditText`. I have played with the `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` for all fields concerned without achieving the desired affect.
I tried the `TableLayout`, but since I have the requirement to shift the `EditText` value right if there is no `TextView` to the right (the Suffix or "US" in this instance), I don't think that will work (unless I am missing something there) so I have landed with the following, which I think is getting close and which represents the current screen shot above:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Test" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="12456"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="US" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need :)

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Test" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/entry"
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="$" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/currency"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="12456"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currency"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="US" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use change to LinearLayout and use `android:layout_weight`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="XXdp"
        android:text="$" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="XXdp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="12456"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="XXdp"
        android:text="US" />

</LinearLayout>
```

See this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html